# EventKit alternatives

Tags: swift, calendar, eventkit, tvos

I have a tvOS application and I want to integrate a calendar. I want to know what alternatives do I have since the EventKit was removed.

thank you!

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Swift/EventKit.html

Comment: Alternatives for doing exactly what? EventKit provides access to the iOS calendar database, tvOS seems to have no calendar database, hence accessing it is unlikely to be your goal ... ;-) Summary: Elaborate what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: thank you for response "hnh" ...I have a 7min workout and i want to implement a "progress calendar"